# Настройка CI GitHub Actions + Allure

Tags: java, github-pages, yaml, github-actions

Всем привет!
Написал автотесты на Java, пытаюсь настроить непрерывную интеграцию через GitHub с формированием allure отчета.
Прогон тестов настроить получилось, а вот вместо allure отчета получаю страницу на которой указано название моего репозитория и всё. Может кто-то сталкивался с такой же проблемой, помогите пожалуйста. Подозреваю, что ошибка может быть в этой строке:

> PERSONAL_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

Ниже скрины и логи

Вот мой .yaml файл:

```
name: Test

#on: [push]
on: workflow_dispatch # - для ручного запуска

jobs:
  test:
    # где заускаем
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # что делаем
    steps:
      # выкачиваем репозиторий
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      # настраиваем java
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'zulu'
          java-version: '11'
      - uses: Xotabu4/selenoid-github-action@v2
      # запускаем тесты
      - run: ./gradlew clean test -Dselenide.remote=http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
      # скачиваем историю тестов
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        if: always()
        continue-on-error: true
        with:
          ref: gh-pages
          path: gh-pages
      # генерируем отчет
      - uses: simple-elf/allure-report-action@master
        if: always()
        with:
          gh_pages: gh-pages
          allure_results: build/allure-results
          allure_report: allure-report
          allure_history: allure-history
      # публикуем отчет
      - uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v2
        if: always()
        env:
          PERSONAL_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          PUBLISH_BRANCH: gh-pages
          PUBLISH_DIR: allure-history
```

Большую его часть я брал отсюда: https://github.com/simple-elf/allure-report-action

Меня интересует вот этот шаг - шаг публикации отчета (скрин ниже)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот лог этого шага:

```
Run peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v2
  with:
    emptyCommits: true
    keepFiles: false
    forceOrphan: false
    tagOverwrite: false
  env:
    JAVA_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Zulu_jdk/11.0.20-8/x64
    JAVA_HOME_11_X64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Zulu_jdk/11.0.20-8/x64
    PERSONAL_TOKEN: ***
    PUBLISH_BRANCH: gh-pages
    PUBLISH_DIR: allure-history
/usr/bin/docker run --name c9a4a5fd81fc0fd0f84553b0b10cd3a9b5ec78_91746b --label c9a4a5 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "JAVA_HOME" -e "JAVA_HOME_11_X64" -e "PERSONAL_TOKEN" -e "PUBLISH_BRANCH" -e "PUBLISH_DIR" -e "INPUT_EMPTYCOMMITS" -e "INPUT_KEEPFILES" -e "INPUT_FORCEORPHAN" -e "INPUT_USERNAME" -e "INPUT_USEREMAIL" -e "INPUT_COMMITMESSAGE" -e "INPUT_TAGNAME" -e "INPUT_TAGMESSAGE" -e "INPUT_TAGOVERWRITE" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_ENVIRONMENT" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/demo_qa/demo_qa":"/github/workspace" c9a4a5:fd81fc0fd0f84553b0b10cd3a9b5ec78
INFO: Deploy to alecloz/demo_qa
INFO: setup with PERSONAL_TOKEN
Cloning into '/github/home/ghpages_24956'...
warning: Could not find remote branch gh-pages to clone.
fatal: Remote branch gh-pages not found in upstream origin
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /github/workspace/allure-history/.git/
Switched to a new branch 'gh-pages'
INFO: Allowing empty commits: true
[gh-pages (root-commit) 310df22] Automated deployment: Sun Jul 23 09:22:04 UTC 2023 e9d331fbbec39a10b930c2b75d2c23c072a12f42
 88 files changed, 7637 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 10/app.js
 create mode 100644 10/data/attachments/5c9ec965b44d1cac.png
 create mode 100644 10/data/attachments/7cbff5f043cb5037.html
 create mode 100644 10/data/attachments/892acbd17aa9f0c3.txt
 create mode 100644 10/data/attachments/d3706d14eeb717fa.png
 create mode 100644 10/data/attachments/d3888fbda3714555.html
 create mode 100644 10/data/attachments/fa7d1f487b57d7a6.png
 create mode 100644 10/data/behaviors.csv
 create mode 100644 10/data/behaviors.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/categories.csv
 create mode 100644 10/data/categories.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/packages.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/suites.csv
 create mode 100644 10/data/suites.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/16fc02c08cda7217.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/20d4314e0e686881.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/27e8982519a8703c.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/294479a5aaa6d929.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/2cdfbd63b6cf9974.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/2fc3f4510dacd679.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/39ff17b68cb1a77f.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/3bf8a090484b88da.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/5107fdb5fb8fb5a9.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/5f1bd778b5019171.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/63aac98c9c500f28.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/63e0978b81152881.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/644892d15958a72d.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/680a520ad859d1ba.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/6860b9d70a764c61.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/6d656e6bc56e7b80.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/6e9a73ba924f98b4.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/71456d032f798ed3.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/7146d87b88cfb6cc.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/71abdde1c6cfd9c7.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/735b748540f1cde5.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/788ec2f5901343bf.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/7d0a8448ce216398.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/815f4b92dc56bb80.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/8cc0c7a8d28fb514.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/9428e7b758449d5f.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/9eaebb09e43b38ee.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/a03cfae663f03e44.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/c4d1d05374d7fec1.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/c76cac9aee42735c.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/c8bc71767e4a9816.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/cc73aa687275a68f.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/d459b45215cdf0ef.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/dbc91a46b106be59.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/e1c9888a1f893ab1.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/e909b5e876a21641.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/eb9dbc6fe0ad2806.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/test-cases/ed0260a96c82efc.json
 create mode 100644 10/data/timeline.json
 create mode 100644 10/export/influxDbData.txt
 create mode 100644 10/export/mail.html
 create mode 100644 10/export/prometheusData.txt
 create mode 100644 10/favicon.ico
 create mode 100644 10/history/categories-trend.json
 create mode 100644 10/history/duration-trend.json
 create mode 100644 10/history/history-trend.json
 create mode 100644 10/history/history.json
 create mode 100644 10/history/retry-trend.json
 create mode 100644 10/index.html
 create mode 100644 10/plugins/behaviors/index.js
 create mode 100644 10/plugins/packages/index.js
 create mode 100644 10/plugins/screen-diff/index.js
 create mode 100644 10/plugins/screen-diff/styles.css
 create mode 100644 10/styles.css
 create mode 100644 10/widgets/behaviors.json
 create mode 100644 10/widgets/categories-trend.json
 create mode 100644 10/widgets/categories.json
 create mode 100644 10/widgets/duration-trend.json
 create mode 100644 10/widgets/duration.json
 create mode 100644 10/widgets/environment.json
 create mode 100644 10/widgets/executors.json
 create mode 100644 10/widgets/history-trend.json
 create mode 100644 10/widgets/launch.json
 create mode 100644 10/widgets/retry-trend.json
 create mode 100644 10/widgets/severity.json
 create mode 100644 10/widgets/status-chart.json
 create mode 100644 10/widgets/suites.json
 create mode 100644 10/widgets/summary.json
 create mode 100644 index.html
 create mode 100644 last-history/categories-trend.json
 create mode 100644 last-history/duration-trend.json
 create mode 100644 last-history/history-trend.json
 create mode 100644 last-history/history.json
 create mode 100644 last-history/retry-trend.json
remote: Permission to alecloz/demo_qa.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/alecloz/demo_qa.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Я пробовал генерировать токен и добавлять его вот сюда:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После этого пробовал сюда же вставлять не токен, а ssh ключ публичный. Ошибка 403 исчезала, но гитхаб начинал жаловаться на неправильный путь к удаленному репозиторию

В пейджах выставлена вот такая ветка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот страница на которой должен генерироваться Allure отчет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас отчет выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]